# Viewpager not saving Fragment states

Tags: java, android

First of all I would like to thank the stackoverflow community. Thanks to you I solved so much problems! Usually I bang my head over the wall for hours and I find the solution here (98% percent of the time). This time I would like to share my problem.

This is the first app I'm developing. I have one activity (is this bad?). My app structure is the following: Nav drawer which contains four items - two viewpagers and two static fragments. The viewpagers contains lists with data and if you click on one of the items from the list you are present with a detail page which again is a viewpager. When you are on the detail page you can click and advance to other fragment. The problem is that when I advance to the other fragment onSavedInstance is not called for the viewpagerdetails and I can't retain the fragment state. onSavedInstance will be called if I pass to the FragmentPagerAdapter getFragmentManager(), instead of getChildFragmentManager(), but if I do this when I navigate back, the viewpager items are blank. I have tried using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, but when I click back from the 'other fragment' to return to viewpager details the app crashes with the following error:  Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 0. I have looked over the internet, but I didn't found a working solution. Some say that the problem is from the adapter, but I tried this solution and it didn't work. Also I want to manually retain my fragment state, please don't offer me the fix with the configchanges in the app manifest. I have tried to call onSavedInstanceState from the onStop method, but when I return to the fragment the saved state is empty. Should I implement this with a static variable in my mainActivity?

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class DetailsSlideAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private FragmentManager manager;
private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;
private Resources res;

public DetailsSlideAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Resources res) {
    super(fm);
    this.manager = fm;
    navMenuTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.detailTabs);
    this.res = res;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            DetailsInfo info = new DetailsInfo();
            return info;
        case 1:
            DetailsCast cast = new DetailsCast();
            return cast;
        case 2:
            DetailsOverview overview = new DetailsOverview();
            return overview;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return navMenuTitles[0];
        case 1:
            return navMenuTitles[1];
        case 2:
            return navMenuTitles[2];
        default:
            return navMenuTitles[1];
    }
}
```

Viewpager details:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    DetailsSlideAdapter = new DetailsSlideAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getResources());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.DetailsPager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(DetailsSlideAdapter);

    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
    // it's PagerAdapter set.
    mSlidingTabLayout = (DetailsSlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabSelected));
}
```

If other code is needed I will post it. Thanks.

**EDIT using FragmentStateAdapter:**
App crashes: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 0. On the internet people say that the problem is from the adapter, but I tried this solution and it didn't work. Code:

```
public class DetailsSlideAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private FragmentManager manager;
private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;
private Resources res;
SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();


public DetailsSlideAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Resources res) {
    super(fm);
    this.manager = fm;
    navMenuTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.detailTabs);
    this.res = res;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            DetailsInfo info = new DetailsInfo();
            return info;
        case 1:
            DetailsCast cast = new DetailsCast();
            return cast;
        case 2:
            DetailsOverview overview = new DetailsOverview();
            return overview;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return navMenuTitles[0];
        case 1:
            return navMenuTitles[1];
        case 2:
            return navMenuTitles[2];
        default:
            return navMenuTitles[1];
    }
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}
```

Comment: extend your adapter from FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: Well currently I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and I'm catching the error: 'Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 0'. Also I had to write my backStack, since onSaveInstanceState is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this? [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

From the Docs:

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each
>   page. This class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's
>   state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said in my question:  I have tried using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, but when I click back from the 'other fragment' to return to viewpager details the app crashes with the following error: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 0. Also I noticed that onSavednstance state is not called.